# How would I dynamically sort an array of objects by the key names? - The names differ by numeric characters only

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, sorting, javascript-objects

This is the array of objects I'm fetching (the source isn't mine so I can't change the structure of this data server-side in any way).

```
[
  { phase4: 3 },
  { phase3: 4 },
  { phase2: 14 },
  { phase1: 46 },
  { phase6: 12 },
  { phase5: 1 }
]
```

Is there a way I could dynamically sort the given array to the following?

```
[
  { phase1: 46 },
  { phase2: 14 },
  { phase3: 4 },
  { phase4: 3 },
  { phase5: 12 },
  { phase6: 1 },
]
```

**UPDATE**

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/theMachine97/t9046o2r)

Comment: If you're going to downvote, at least explain why? I've been looking it up for the past 1.5 hours - the question isn't unclear, nor is it not useful???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort with the customised sort algorithm. You just need to grab the key using `Object.keys(obj)[0]`

```js
const arr = [
  { phase4: 3 },
  { phase3: 4 },
  { phase2: 14 },
  { phase1: 46 },
  { phase6: 12 },
  { phase5: 1 },
];

const result = arr.sort((a, b) => {
  const prop1 = Object.keys(a)[0];
  const prop2 = Object.keys(b)[0];
  
  if (prop1 < prop2) return -1;
  if (prop1 > prop2) return 1;
  return 0;
});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: It would be easy for me to understand what is the problem if you could give me your code snippet on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) or [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: sorry, yeah of course: https://jsfiddle.net/dxfbLz2u/1

Comment: You are calling `totalPhaseVal()` after the sorting so you just need to run the function `totalPhaseVal` before `sort` . [SOLUTION](https://jsfiddle.net/esr0kz5a/1/). Evrything else if perfect...

Comment: Jeez, I've been looking at this for hours now and THAT was the issue, not the sorting I had 2 hours ago. Thank you so much dude.

Comment: You just need to debug step by step. You mainly missed the debug step... Well we all learn from out mistakes

Answer (score 0):

You could just take the number from the key in each object and use a numeric sort()

```js
const d=[
  { phase4: 3 },
  { phase3: 4 },
  { phase2: 14 },
  { phase1: 46 },
  { phase6: 12 },
  { phase5: 1 },
  { phase11: 11 },
  { phase22: 22 }
]

const keyNum = (e) => Object.keys(e)[0].match(/\d+$/)[0];

const res = d.sort((a,b) => keyNum(a) - keyNum(b))

console.log(res)
```

Comment: Thank you for responding to my question. Both of the solutions you provided work!